# Charts.js polar area scales

Tags: chart.js

When Charts.js (Version: 2.1.3) renders my polar area charts for low data values the scale is drawn with fractional values:
[Example polar area chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAa1d.jpg)

The fractions do not make sense in the context of my data (student numbers). I would rather display a scale of whole numbers, or no scale. I have tried to change the chart options, looked at and tested various examples, searched for answers on this site and elsewhere, but no success yet. Any advice please?

Example of my code:

```
    var ML_Chart_obj = new Chart(ctx,
{
    type: "polarArea",
    data: {
      datasets: [{
          data: [0,1,0],
          backgroundColor: [
              "rgba(060,186,084,0.6)"
              ,"rgba(244,194,013,0.6)"
              ,"rgba(219,050,054,0.6)"
          ],
          label: ""
      }],
      labels: [
          "Active, on target"
          ,"Unspecified start or end date"
          ,"Active, at risk"
      ]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
         xAxes: [{
         display:false
         }]
      },
      legend: {
        display: false
      }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

A little too late, but this is how you do it.

```
options{
    scale: {
        ticks: {
            stepSize: 1
        }
    }
}
```